# Loading testing environment in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, rails-console

I am trying to load the test environment for unit testing and used several commands like
1. RAILS_ENV = test
2. rails console test
3. RAILS_ENV=test rails console

I am getting the same error each time(undefined method 'symbolize keys').

Can someone let me know what to do to load the test environment ?

Comment: `rails console test` is correct.  Have a look at your `database.yml` file; this type of error can occur with a yaml syntax error.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using automated testing, your test environment will be loaded automatically.
If you want to switch to the test environment in your console:

```
rails console test
```

The error you get is telling me there is something wrong in your code.

Comment: Hi Miotsu, Its not automated testing and I am trying to switch test environment. I have already used the command which is mentioned but still it showing error.How can wrong code will affect in changing the environment ? Can you please explain about this. I am just trying to change the environment thats all

Comment: different environments have different settings, which can be set in database.yml and confi/environments/ . something might work in one environment and not in the other.

Comment: You are referring to database.yml code and I thought of my project code, oh gosh !!!! Anyhow the database.yml is fine and I got the solution by some googling and trial and hit bcos it always works. Thanks !!!

Comment: Suggestion:  Please post the resolution so that future users will be able to find not only the question but the answer.  Thanks.

Comment: RAILS_ENV=test rake db:create, this helps me in changing the environment and creating the database for my unit test